# Arduino never powers on after sleep

Tags: arduino, embedded

I'm making a funny matrix dice with Arduino and I'm breaking my brain to make interrupts work properly. I have two interrupts one is used to throw the dice (state_change) the other is used to sleep Arduino (arduino_off). The interrupt to play the dice is ok, but I have some problem to wake up Arduino after shutdown. I tried to throw interrupt with options HIGH, LOW and RAISE. The best configuration seem to keep high the pin and ground it to throw the interrupt. I'm using an USB Voltage and Amp meter between my pc and Arduino. I see that I can shutdown Arduino if I set the interrupt to LOW with a digital write inside the if statement. The problem is waking it up. I think is impossible to make it with another digital write because the loop is stopped, but if I try manually with a button sometimes it wake up but sleep again, like if there is a bouncing problem.

```
#include <MaxMatrix.h>

#include <avr/pgmspace.h>
#include <avr/sleep.h>
#include <avr/power.h>

const byte A[] = {
 4, 8, B1111110, B0010001, B0010001, B1111110 //A
};

const byte empty[] = {
8, 8, B00000000, B00000000, B00000000, B00000000,
B00000000, B00000000, B00000000, B00000000 // all leds off
};

const byte full[] = {
8, 8, B11111111, B11111111, B11111111, B11111111,
B11111111, B11111111, B11111111, B11111111  // all leds on
};

const byte face[] = {
8, 8, B00000000, B00000000, B00000000, B00011000, 
B00011000, B00000000, B00000000, B00000000, // ONE
8, 8, B00000011, B00000011, B00000000, B00000000, 
B00000000, B00000000, B11000000, B11000000, // TWO 
8, 8, B11000000, B11000000, B00000000, B00011000, 
B00011000, B00000000, B00000011, B00000011, // THREE
8, 8, B11000011, B11000011, B00000000, B00000000, 
B00000000, B00000000, B11000011, B11000011, // FOUR
8, 8, B11000011, B11000011, B00000000, B00011000, 
B00011000, B00000000, B11000011, B11000011, // FIVE
8, 8, B11011011, B11011011, B00000000, B11011011, 
B11011011, B00000000, B11011011, B11011011, // SIX


};


int din_pin = 4; 
int load_pin = 5; 
int clock_pin = 6; 

int interrupt_pin_real_one = 1; //atmega = PD3(int1) = 1 
//arduino mapping = pin 3 (write the real one)
int interrupt_pin_real_zero = 0;
int interrupt_pin_mapped_one = 3;
int interrupt_pin_mapped_zero = 2;

int matrix_number = 4;

// max tollerance to needed to change state
volatile int bounce_tol = 300; 

volatile int bounce = 0; // count bouncing time/button pressed

long time = 0; // store the timestamp;

// max time before cpu sleep
// 60000 = 1 minute
// 1000 = 1 second
long time_limit = 1000 * 5; 

int i = 0;

volatile int state = LOW;

// check standby mode 
// normal = false, standby enabled = true;
boolean low_profile = false; 
boolean first_run = true; // check if the dice never rolled
boolean one_loop = true; // to execute the if statement only ones


MaxMatrix m(din_pin, load_pin, clock_pin, matrix_number);

void setup(){

  Serial.begin(9600);


  m.init();
  m.setIntensity(15); // dot matix intensity 0-15


  pinMode(din_pin,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(load_pin,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(clock_pin,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(interrupt_pin_mapped_one, INPUT);
  pinMode(interrupt_pin_mapped_zero, INPUT);

  // no pull up needed
  // BE CAREFULL IN PCB DESIGN NOT CONNECT TO GND
  digitalWrite(interrupt_pin_mapped_one, HIGH); 
  digitalWrite(interrupt_pin_mapped_zero, HIGH);


  attachInterrupt(interrupt_pin_real_one, state_changer, LOW);
  attachInterrupt(interrupt_pin_real_zero, arduino_off, LOW); 


}

// toggle power down / up
void arduino_off(){


set_sleep_mode(SLEEP_MODE_IDLE);   // sleep mode is set here

sleep_enable();          // enables the sleep bit in the mcucr register
                         // so sleep is possible. just a safety pin

/* Now it is time to enable an interrupt. We do it here so an
 * accidentally pushed interrupt button doesn't interrupt
 * our running program. if you want to be able to run
 * interrupt code besides the sleep function, place it in
 * setup() for example.
 *
 * In the function call attachInterrupt(A, B, C)
 * A   can be either 0 or 1 for interrupts on pin 2 or 3.  
 *
 * B   Name of a function you want to execute at interrupt for A.
 *
 * C   Trigger mode of the interrupt pin. can be:
 *             LOW        a low level triggers
 *             CHANGE     a change in level triggers
 *             RISING     a rising edge of a level triggers
 *             FALLING    a falling edge of a level triggers
 *
 * In all but the IDLE sleep modes only LOW can be used.
 */

attachInterrupt(interrupt_pin_real_zero, arduino_off, HIGH); 


sleep_mode();            // here the device is actually put to sleep!!
// THE PROGRAM CONTINUES FROM HERE AFTER WAKING 


sleep_disable();         // first thing after waking from sleep:
                         // disable sleep...
detachInterrupt(interrupt_pin_real_zero);      
                         // wakeUpNow code will not be executed
                         // during normal running time.


}

   // dice rooollll!!!!!
   void state_changer(){

     if(bounce >= bounce_tol){

       if(low_profile == true){

          //CLKPR = 0x01;  
          low_profile = false;
       }

     Serial.print("rolling \n");
    //digitalWrite(interrupt_pin_mapped_zero, LOW);

    state = !state;
    bounce = 0;


    }
    bounce++;  
 }

 void magic_box(int sleep){

   int num_1 = random(6);
   int num_2 = random(6);
   int num_3 = random(6);
   int num_4 = random(6);


   m.writeSprite(0, 0, &face[num_1*10]);
   m.writeSprite(8, 0, &face[num_2*10]);
   m.writeSprite(16, 0, &face[num_3*10]);
   m.writeSprite(24, 0, &face[num_4*10]);

   delay(sleep);
 }

 void rolling(){

   for(i=0;i<=10;i++){
   magic_box(50);

   }

   for(i=0;i<=6;i++){
     magic_box(200);
   } 

   for(i=0;i<=2;i++){
      magic_box(500);

   }

}


void clear_matrix(){
   m.writeSprite(0, 0, empty);
   m.writeSprite(8, 0, empty);
   m.writeSprite(16, 0, empty);
   m.writeSprite(24, 0, empty);  
}



void loop() {

  //digitalWrite(interrupt_pin_mapped_zero, HIGH);  

  if(((millis() - time) >= time_limit) 
     && first_run == false && one_loop == true){

     //debug
     Serial.print("stop \n");

     //sleep_enable();
     //energy.PowerDown();
     //CLKPR = 0x04;

     clear_matrix();

    // throw the interrupt to powerdown the Arduino

    //digitalWrite(interrupt_pin_mapped_zero, LOW);

    //debug
    Serial.print("after stop \n");
    low_profile = true;

    one_loop = false;
 }






if(state == HIGH){

   if(bounce < bounce_tol){  


     //digitalWrite(interrupt_pin_mapped_zero, LOW);


     rolling();

     state = LOW;
     bounce = 0;
     first_run = false;
     one_loop = true;
     time = millis(); // time stamp of the last rolling
   }


 }



}
```

here there is the video to "make an idea" of what I'm speaking about. https://youtu.be/INCNUYrVASQ

P.S: Can you tell me the magic secret to auto indent 4 space to show text-code in stack overflow.... use a day for spacing every line instead of coding should be stressing :)

tnx bye :)

Comment: TL;DR Please provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: `Can you tell me the magic secret to auto indent 4 space to show text-code in stack overflow`: Select the text, hit Ctrl+K

Comment: `attachInterrupt(interrupt_pin_real_zero, arduino_off, HIGH);` There is no HIGH interrupt, only LOW, CHANGE, RISING, FALLING. Why does the `arduino_off` function attach an interrupt handler to itself?

Comment: Can you clarify what you are trying to do? You want to press a button, and make the whole things sleep (including the LEDs?) to save power, is that it? And then press the button again to wake it? Is that the idea?

Comment: yes untill Arduino is on the button is used to change the number of the led matrix, when is off is used to wake it up